# mysql merge changes from a different table with same description

Tags: mysql

I have two servers A and B with mysql installed on it. Currently my site is loading from server A.

I took a database backup from database A and restored it on server B on a particular date (say oct17). Since the site was live, it kept updating the database on server A until  oct24.  Accidentally I made the server B live(say oct 24). So I am missing contents after oct 17 and before oct 24 in the database B. Since server B is live now, its being updating now. How can I add the missing contents to the database B ?

One thing I am planning is to try copy all the contents after oct 24 from database B to the tables in database A . After updating all the tables, dump the database from A and restore to database B.....

Any idea to accomplish the issue ? any tool to compare and update the values ?

Thanks,

Comment: You could do IF NOT EXISTS(...) then ..., i.e. if data From A does not Exist in B, then add it to B, and such...

Comment: @MisterSpock : Thanks for your quick reply. I am not much familiar with the command line. I have phpmyadmin for both the servers. If I find the row in server B after which the updating is coming, is there any way to dump only that one ? or any tools to perform the comparison ?

Comment: You could check `mysqldbcompare` from [MySQL Utilities](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/mysqldbcompare.html). It can generate a set of SQL statements that will update database B to match database A.

Comment: Thanks for all your help.. Unfortunately I already did it by exporting the rows of each table I wanted. I copied the command from the exported sql file and put it in the table's SQL section. I know this is the tedious way to do that. Anyway I need to have a look into the mysaqldbcompare to do it more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if `mysqldbcompare` from [MySQL Utilities](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/mysqldbcompare.html) can do the job for you.

```
mysqldbcompare --server1=A --server2=B --changes-for=B --difftype=sql
```

Should generate SQL statements that will make server B match server A.